# How i can show and hide a form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to show a hidden div with css and jquery: Actually I  have the next  code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li class=""><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <!--<li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Recetas<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Carne</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Verduras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pescado</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>-->
        <li><a href="suscripcions.html">Suscripciones</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><form class="navbar-form nav navbar-nav " role="search">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="search" />

                <button type="submit" id="AdvanceSearchButton"><i  class="fa fa-search" ></i></button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
            </li>


        <li><a href="register.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a id="log" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

I want show  my div AdvanceSearch when the button AdvanceServiceButton is pressed. 

<div id="AdvanceSearch">
    <h1> DIV for show </h1>
</div>
```

For this, im using the next script with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#AdvanceSearchButton').click(function(){
                $('#AdvanceSearch').fadeIn(1000)
            })/* Randall */
            });
```

My problem is that when the button is pressed, the div is showed and hidden. 
The problem is the button, because with a customized button this work correctly, but not with the used button from boostrap, This can be the problem?

Regards.

Comment: Since its a submit button I think you have to use prevent default so it wont submit and have you try to use toggle?

Answer (score 0):

You create a button inside a form, of type `submit`, so the default action when you click a submit button is to submit the form. In your attached javascript, you show the advanced-search form, but do not block the submit of the form.

I would propose the following mark-up (btw your HTML's indentation is all over the place, at least make a little effort to make code readable) :

```
<form class="navbar-form nav navbar-nav" role="search">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="search" />
    <a href="#" id="advanced-search-button" class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
    </a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And then you can just write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#advanced-search-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#AdvanceSearch').fadeIn(1000);
  })
});
```

The `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` make sure this is the only action that is executed when the link (which will look like a button) is clicked.